# Read a form bean property to pass on to a forward

Tags: struts-1, struts-config

I am using struts 1.3. I have a an action I am reusing in 3 different cases. The form bean backing this has a property that has the complete path(passed from the jsp) to which the action should forward in case of success/failure(the path is different for each case depending on what the user is doing). How do I specify this for the input attribute of the action in the struts config to read from that form bean property.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is return a dynamic `ActionForward` from your `Action` class. This lets you use an `ActionForward` that isn't defined in your`struts-config.xml`

```
return new ActionForward(path_to_forward, redirect_true_or_false);
```

This doesn't help you for the input, which expects a `JSP` and not an `ActionForward`, but you should be able to do that in the `ActionForm`'s `validate()` method. The first parameter passed into that method is an `ActionMapping`. On that object, you should be able to call `setInput(String)` with the path of your `JSP`.  I have not tried this, but it looks like it should work.